# how updates happen when I add my VMs to DSC and availability sets

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-machine

If I add two of my VMs to desired state configuration(DSC) nodes with same DSC configuration and add those two VMs to a single availability set with update domains=2, how the updates will happen to those VMs? Will the updates happen at a time or one after the other?

**Note:** Assume I made some software updates or enabled some features in windows through my powershell script.

Answer (score 0):

For VMs in availability sets, update domains are updated one at a time. All VMs in one update domain (UD) are paused, updated and then resumed before planned maintenance moves on to the next UD.

Comment: I know that. But is it the same when it is clubbed with DSC? and if yes what will be the situation if I have 1000 VMs under same DSC and 100 update domains? Will update happens one by one?

Comment: Update to VM will happen one after another.